# How can I fetch only ID list in gorm many2many associations

Tags: postgresql, go, microservices, go-gorm

I have a scenario where I have many to many relationship between two tables which are in different databases related to different microservices. Lets say I have table Post and Author. There is many to many relationship between these tables. But my Author table is stored in another database. In my Post service I can fetch all the author's list.

Now the table describing many to many relationship (i.e post_authors) is in Post service. I want something to fetch list of author ids associated with a post when I fetch posts using db.Find(), using gorm associations. And want to do in one query rather than looping through posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Post struct {
  ID int 
  Authors []Author `gorm:"many2many: post_authors;"`
 
}

type Author struct {
  ID int 
}
```

You can try the code as following

```
var posts []Post
db.Where("id in (?)" , []int{1,2,3}).Preload("Authors").Find(&posts)
```

the gorm will load post with authors